# Problem: Moving lines vertically closes folds

Tags: folding

When I move lines with `m` (e.g. `:m+1`) all my folds are closed. I can then open the folding with `zv` again and the cursor will be at the position I moved to.
I use folding with `{{{ }}}` marks and have `set foldmethod=marker` in my .vimrc.

How can I prevent vim from closing folds when moving lines?

Comment: I can't reproduce this using `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N`. It might be an issue with your vimrc or a plugin.

Comment: Happens for me even with -u NONE -U NONE -N. I use v7.4 on arch linux

Comment: @EvergreenTree I have the same problem. With `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N fold-test` and just setting `foldmethod=marker`. I'm running Vim 7.4.712 on Arch. If I try the same with Vim on Vim 7.4.160 on CentOS 7, I get exactly the opposite results (all folds open when using `:m+1`). And Vim 7.2.441 on CentOS 6 works fine... All `fold*` settings seem to be the same on these machines.

Comment: That is very strange.  This seems like a bug.

Comment: That might be caused by patch 7.4.700 which tries to prevent, that folds get invalid on :move commands

Comment: Same issue here with Vim 7.4 on Debian 8. Is this worth a bugreport?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, same here. Yes it is the patch without doubt. Do you know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: @Reman try setting foldmethod=manual

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, It still creates problems. I removed the folds at all. I wish that the patch 7.4.700 was not included.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable folding before doing `:m+1` by using `zi`. And then enable it again with `zi`.

You can also add a special mapping for that in your .vimrc :

```
""move line up/down with Shift+up/down
nnoremap <S-Up> zi:m-2<CR>zi
nnoremap <S-Down> zi:m+<CR>zi
inoremap <S-Up> <Esc>zi:m-2<CR>zia
inoremap <S-Down> <Esc>zi:m+<CR>zia
```

Comment: This worked for me. (although I used different bindings)

Answer (score 1):

Folding is a pretty complicated mechanism (see [another answer I gave about folds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563239/folding-of-scala-imports-in-vim/34581288#34581288) for a nuanced discussion of folding scanning).

In order to give a complete answer we will need to see what type of plugins you are loading when booting up an instance of vim.

I'd bet that there are a few plugins that are mucking with the default vim settings (`vim -u NONE` should have reproduced this). Any plugin that changes the `foldmethod` is a likely cause (I'd try to remove them 1 by 1 and see what causes the issue)

If you don't want to muck with your plugins at all I'd recommend manually tweaking the syntax + parsing settings and then open a test buffer to confirm your functionality. It can be a frustrating journey to get it to play nicely but with some relentless digging in `:help` you should be able to wrangle the beast that is folding.